# My windows 7 downloads files with appended lines

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, wget, file-download

I have a windows 7 on my old laptop which don't support newer OS so i keep that as a test machine for various codes.

Most of the times I use `wget` for transferring files from my new laptop to the old one and most of the time when I open the file it has appended lines. I mean, all the lines are just in one line.

Not only `wget` but I have made a `vba` code to download files and it still has them in just one line. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're downloading text files from Linux, most likely your problem
is the Linux end-of-line which is badly recognized on Windows.

Windows uses "Carriage-Return Line-Feed" (`\r\n`) as the line ending.
Linux/Unix and MacOS use just Line-Feed (`\n`).

To convert Linux line endings to Windows, you could use the
[Unix2Dos utility](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html).

Comment: Yeah im downloading files from linix but couldn't find a binary for `unix2dos` utility in that link. I found the source somewhere but I couldn't read that file also. Although weird enough some file still runs

Comment: The binary is [here](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix/dos2unix-7.4.2-win64.zip) inside the `bin` folder. And yes, some programs accept both kinds of end-of-line.